# Полымя - падежи

Tags: грамматика, склонение

Все словари сходятся на том, что у слова ***полымя*** из всех косвенных падежей литературной нормой признается только творительный ("п**о**лымем").

Вот тут и возникает вопрос, как это понимать. Понятно, что это епархия филологов, а простые смертные должны принять к сведению. Но очень странным кажется, что именно творительный, наименее, пожалуй, востребованный из всех русских падежей, сохранил эту форму (причем только для варианта с первым ударным слогом - п**о**лымя).

Меня бы устроило то, например, объяснение, что творительный сохранился в каком-то фразеологизме, но так ведь нет. 
Или что парадигма у этого слова неполноценна исторически - это если остальные формы никогда и не существовали, а творительный падеж образовался окказионально. Так ведь тоже нет. Родственное "пламя" (по сути - фонетический вариант) вполне функционально во всех падежах, правда с особым типом склонения - разносклоняемым и с наращением.
Ну пусть не исчерпывающее объяснение, хотя бы предпосылки к такой ситуации - существуют?

Comment: Интересный случай... Если я не ошибаюсь, отчасти похожа на эту ситуация со словом *щи*: поставленное в родительный падеж, оно звучит как *щей*, а в уменьшительной форме —*щец*, причём для последнего варианта существует лишь родительный падеж. Видать, в русском языке есть некоторое количество слов, которые не всегда можно просклонять обычным способом.

Comment: @Ольга. Да, *щец и дровец* - два слова-инвалида, не имеющие других падежных форм. Но это другой случай. Отсутвие других падежей объясняется там отчасти фонетически, но в основном тем, что это не столько уменьшительная форма, сколько родительный-II (партитив), аналогичный "(ложка) сахару", "(рюмка) коньяку"... Другие падежи партитив не обслуживает. Даже если это не точное объяснение, всё-таки какая-то идея такового. А у нас-то нет ни малейшей зацепки за этот хитрый творительный.

Comment: Хотя на одну мысль вы меня навели. Надо посмотреть, из чего вообще складывался современный творительный падеж. Может, там и есть какая ниточка.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, дело не в одном падеже, а в самом слове? Оно вышло из употребления, исконно русское заменилось старославянским.

Пламя ведь старославянизм (ла вместо оло). В древнерусской литературе слово «пламя»("пламы") встречается с XI в., хотя возникло оно гораздо раньше. В живой речи употреблялось  поломя (полымя) - от глагола полми (жечь, сжигать), а в церковной литературе пламы (род. п. пламене).

Парадигму склонения слова поломя называют "вырожденной". Может, потому и выродилась, что  в литературе встречали только церковнославянизм, а нормированный язык - литературный.

У слова пламя парадигма тоже ведь изменилась, перестали употреблять множественное число, а оно было - пламё (позже-пламена).

В письменной речи, особенно в поэзии XIX в., встречаются формы косв. пад. слов на -мя без изменения основы: *Я не знал другого имя (Лерм.); Из пламя и света Рожденное слово (Лерм.); То к темю их прижмет (Крыл.); Между темем и подбородком (Герц.); Пестрая с огромным вымем корова (Л. Толст.)*.

В разг. речи и сейчас постоянны сочетания *сколько время?, нет, не было время*. В письменной речи такое употребление является отступлением от нормы.

В торжественной речи, в поэзии употребляются слова муж. р. пламень и (редко) темень с нулевой флексией в формах им.- вин. п.: *То полудня пламень синий, То рассвета пламень алый (Анн.); Ходит полоумный Старичина, Петуха на темень посадив (Есен.).* Это тоже древний остаток. Говоря о наращении -ен, мы же вспоминаем, что раньше  -ен было во всех падежах, и им. пад. имел форму знамен. В конце слова сочетание -ен- слилось в один носовой гласный звук ( юс малый), носовой гласный со временем перешёл в а (я): из знамен получилось знамя. В остальных же падежах ед. и множ. числа сочетание -ен- сохранилось потому, что оно стояло не в конце слова, а перед гласным: знамени, знаменем, знамёна.

Сущ. пОлымя даётся с пометой устар., но это литературная норма. Остались только словоформы, употреблявшиеся во фразеологизмах и в поэзии для стилизации под старину или народный говор, как у Есенина: *Но дымилась тихая дорога В незакатном полыме озер.*  В отдельных диалектах оно женского рода, употребляются и родительный, и дательный,и винительный, и предложный падежи: из полымя, в полымя, к полымю, о полыме.

Вот и получается: **в живом народном языке падежи сохранились, но это не норма, потому что словоупотребление не зафиксировано в литературе. Там только им., вин. и творительный - то, что осталось в поговорке.**

Answer (score 0):

*Меня бы устроило то, например, объяснение, что творительный сохранился в каком-то фразеологизме, но так ведь нет.*

Не могу согласиться с Вами.

**Пословицы и поговорки, присказки (В.И. Даль):**
*Сорвался с виселицы. Словно его полымем принесло.* (Гульба — пьянство)
*Синя порошина полымем дышит.* (Драка — война)
*Огнем дышит, полымем пышет.*

**Фразеологизм** из повести В.П. Астафьева "Бабушкин праздник":
*Пить-есть чего у них имеется? Как жена твоя родная, жива или мертва? Загуляла или блюдет себя?.. **Или тебе гори все огнем-полымем**?*

**Заговор** (очищение жилья):
*- Ах, ты гой еси, кикимора домовая,

Выходи из горюнина дома скорее,

А не то задерут тебя калеными прутьями,

Сожгут **огнем-полымем** и черной смолой зальют!*

[Интересно, что у [**Даля**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/319558/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%AB%D0%9C%D0%AF) "полымя" — женского рода, а про особенности падежей вообще ничего не говорится:
ПОЛЫМЯ
*жен., вост.* поломя, пламя. Из огня да в полымя. Костер полымясто разгорелся. Полымя из ноздрей, пар (дым) из ушей. От дождя не в воду, от огня не в полымя.]

У Салтыкова-Щедрина ("Сон в летнюю ночь"):
*— Прибегают, это, мужички на пожар, — говорит староста, — а он, сердечный, мальчишечко-то, стоит в окне, в самом значит, **в полыме…***

И у Есенина в "Мечте":
*Я хотел сказать тебе так много,

Что томило душу с ранних пор,

Но дымилась тихая дорога

 В незакатном **полыме** озер.*

Comment: С чем вы не можете согласиться?  Послович надергать - дело нехитрое. В чем тут фразеологичность творительного падежа? Больше никаких положений в процитированном Вами моем тексте и нету.  Вот "огнем-полымем" - еще представляет какой-то интерес, но опять-таки фразеологичность именно творительного - под большим вопросом.